# How to view Play, Pause, Stop and Volume buttons and Viedo in mediaElement controll in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I add media Element control to my WPF application. I want to play video file or audio file.
I played file manually using code. But there are such buttons on the control for stop, play, pause, volume and for video if the file is video? I want to design a user interface for media element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code for having those buttons

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx) can help you